# Is it possible to compile a self-contained ASP.NET Core Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am looking for a way to generate a self-contained EXE that will launch ASP.NET Core (.NET Core). The project will simply serve up some static files from /wwwroot.

I have found a [few](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SelfcontainedNETCoreApplications.aspx) [resources](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luisdem/2016/10/11/net-core-how-to-publish-a-self-contained-application-exe/) that show how to make a Console Application into a self-contained EXE. These resources involve modifying project.json which does not seem to exist (at least on the initial template).

I have not see any that would allow me to do this with an ASP.NET Core application, is this possible or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is.

However, if you can't find a project.json file in the folder of your project, you did something wrong when setting it up.

After you create a new folder for your project, navigate to that folder in the console and create a new web project with this command:

```
dotnet new -t web
```

The project.json file, along with all of the web template files, should be created at this moment.

Open the project.json file and remove (or comment out) the line

```
"type": "platform"
```

You should also add the following values after the "dependencies" block

```
"runtimes": { 
    "win10-x64": {}
},
```

Please note that the "win10-x64" should be changed to match the architecture of the machine your server will be running on. For a complete list of runtime IDs (RID) supported by the .net core, visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/rid-catalog

Save your changes to the project.json file and run the restore command:

```
dotnet restore
```

And then build

```
dotnet build
```

You can find the *.exe file inside the bin/Debug/netcoreapp[version]/[RID].

Please note that if you run this executable from this folder, your models, views and controllers will not be found by the executable and your page will be blank.

Comment: I seemed to have been using an older version of dotnet core (uninstall and installation of the latest version + dotnet new -t web allowed the project.json to show up). Visual Studio 2017 RC is still making the project with no project.json, and no csproj file to add to our existing solution.

Comment: Fixed above using dotnet migrate on preview 3 of dotnet core https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/preview3-download.md. working on confirming the standalone now.

Comment: It appears preview 3's dotnet new -t Web does not generate a project.json file (like VS2017RC). Is there an alternate way to generate an EXE through the csproj/xml ?

Comment: Above answer is correct for the current version of .NET Core CLI (Jan '17). VS2017 RC comes with an alpha build using the new MS Build / XML system.

Comment: Too bad `project.json` is deprecated.